# Installing Omnipay/payu with laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.1, omnipay

I am developing a website using Laravel 5.1 and i need to have a shopping cart set up, i am trying to install Omnipay for this, i have selected three gateways i will be using: Paypal, Stripe and PayU.
My require under composer.json looks like this:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "ignited/laravel-omnipay": "2.*",        
    "omnipay/paypal": "*",
    "omnipay/stripe": "*",
    "omnipay/payu": "*"
},
```

And i am getting error on the payu part alone, this is the error:

> The requested package omnipay/payu * is satisfiable by omnipay/payu[dev-master, 2.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

I read on another post that specifying `"prefer-stable": true,` and `"minimum-stability": "dev"` into the config part of the composer.json would fix the issue but its not working for me, any tips?

Comment: I have used `payum/payum-laravel-package` for multiple payment gateways.
You can try that.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by adding `"prefer-stable": true, "minimum-stability": "dev"` under the config part of the composer.json, NOT inside it, as i stated in the post.
Like so:

```
...
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"      
},
"prefer-stable": true,
"minimum-stability": "dev"
...
```